# Python class attribute counter doesn't increment properly

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am testing Python OOP concept of class and instance attributes.

**Goal:**

Increase the total number of employees (class attribut) each time an instance of the class "Employee" is created.

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0
    raise_amt = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

        Employee.num_of_emps =+ 1

emp_1 = Employee('Brian', 'Rigs', 65000)
emp_2 = Employee('Eric', 'Masson', 65000)
emp_3 = Employee('John', 'Doe', 80000)

print(Employee.num_of_emps)
```

**Expected Result:**
 *Employee.num_of_emps* should be equal to 3

**Actual result:**

```
print(Employee.num_of_emps)
1
```

I should have missed something, any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a minor typo – change `Employee.num_of_emps =+ 1` to `Employee.num_of_emps += 1`. (I.e. `=+` to `+=`).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I glazed over this one : )